# Updating variable on the fly from another variable

Tags: jquery

I am trying to check conditions depending on variable. Long story short :

a. body_size variable updates on the fly as user resizes window. //got this sorted in other post.

b.Then knowing variable body_size I need to update another variable:

If body_size is less/greater/etc than X (value set by me) then SlidesInView should update itself.

Default SlidesInView is 3.

Everything should happen on the fly. Please see snippet below :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var body_size; // this updates correctly

  var resizeTimer;

  function setContainerWidth() {
    body_size = $('.container').width();
  }

  $(window).resize(function() {

    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {

      setContainerWidth();
     

    }, 200);

  });
  setContainerWidth();
  console.log(body_size);

  var SlidesInView = 3; // this should update depending on result below :
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    setContainerWidth(); // to check width on resize?
    if (body_size => 980) {
      SlidesInView = 4; // change SlidesInView above if condition is met.
    } else if (body_size <= 640) {
      SlidesInView = 1; //change SlidesInView above if condition is met.
    }
  });

  console.log(SlidesInView);
  }); // doc ready
```

```css
.container{
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create a second resize event handler. Instead update `slidesInView` in the function you already have executed on each resize: `setContainerWidth`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var body_size, resizeTimer, slidesInView;

  function setContainerWidth() {
    body_size = $('.container').width();
    slidesInView = body_size >= 980 ? 4 
                 : body_size >= 640 ? 3
                 :                    1;
  }

  $(window).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(setContainerWidth, 200);
  });
  setContainerWidth();
});
```

Some remarks:

- `=>` is an invalid comparison operator (it has another meaning in the context of [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)). Use [`>=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Greater_than_or_equal_operator_(%3E)) instead;
- Don't name your variables with a first capital letter. It is common practice to only do that for class/constructor names, not for other variables.
- The [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) (`... ? .... : ...`)  is ideal for how you want to assign a value to `slidesInView`.
- When you call just one function in a `setTimeout`, you can just pass that function as the first argument to `setTimeout` (make sure to not *call* it, but pass the function itself), like I did in above code.

Comment: Thank you for quick response and good tips. Currently it seems that value gets updates on refresh. Example : container width >= 980 ? 4. snippets checks initial value,then I resize browser window to meet next condition and i need to refresh the page. Is there a way to make it change on the fly .To initiate changes as soon as condition changes? Just wondering about mobile devices (landscape versus portrait).

Comment: Sure, but that really is a different question: you want to rebuild the content you have. This question was about updating a variable, not any DOM content. If you have a question about that, I would suggest to post it as a new question, and add the HTML that needs to be rebuilt, explaining how the variable `slidesInView` should influence it. Once you have created the question, feel free to leave a note here, and I could also have a look if you want.

Comment: Thanks. I have created new question. Placed all the code I have there.I would appreciate if you could look at it. here is the link [New Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449005/change-number-of-slides-depending-on-element-width)

Comment: You're welcome. I just started looking at your new question.